# Company closed and using my holiday entitlement for those days

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, employment

I'm a little confused here so hopefully someone can help. I'm from the UK and I get 28 paid holidays a year including bank holidays.

However, the company I work for are closed for 2 days over Christmas, because of this they are currently using 2 days of my holiday entitlement for these days, is it possible for them to use my holiday for days where they are closed?

Comment: Would the alternative be unpaid leave, or would you expect paid (non-Holiday) time off while they are closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they can do that, as long as they tell you about it in advance.

> Your employer can require you to take all or any of your holiday at a particular time, as long as they give you the right notice at the right time and take into account certain agreements between you.

[Source](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/work/time-off-work/holidays-and-holiday-pay/#h-can-you-choose-when-to-take-holiday)

> Employers can:
>
> - tell their staff to take leave, eg bank holidays or Christmas
> - restrict when leave can be taken, eg at certain busy periods
>
> The notice period for this is at least twice as long as the leave they want their staff to take.

[Source](https://www.gov.uk/holiday-entitlement-rights/booking-time-off-) (official government site)

Comment: On a personal note, I am in Germany, which has similar employment laws and I have never been able to work between Christmas and New Year's. Always had to take between 4 and 6 days off.